# isp-dhcp-server, ipv6, WARNING: Host declarations are global. They are not limited to the scope you declared them in

Tags: debian, dhcp, ipv6, interface

Ciao, this is weird. Everything is working, but I cannot assign static ipv6 addresses.

**error**

```
Jun 12 10:19:15 server dhcpd[2768]: WARNING: Host declarations are global.  They are not limited to the scope you declared them in.
Jun 12 10:19:15 server dhcpd[2770]: WARNING: Host declarations are global.  They are not limited to the scope you declared them in.
```

**interface**

```
iface enp2s0 inet6 static
    metric 10
    address 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::20
    netmask 64
    gateway 2001:470:1f1a:5b3::1

auto he-ipv6
iface he-ipv6 inet6 v4tunnel
        address 2001:470:1f1a:5b3::2
        netmask 64
        endpoint 216.66.87.14
        local 192.168.78.20
        ttl 255
        gateway 2001:470:1f1a:5b3::1
```

**radvd.conf**

```
interface enp2s0 {
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    prefix 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::/64 {
    };
};
```

**dhcpd6.conf**

```
default-lease-time 2592000;
preferred-lifetime 604800;
option dhcp-renewal-time 3600;
option dhcp-rebinding-time 7200;
allow leasequery;
option dhcp6.name-servers 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::20,2001:4860:4860::8888,2001:4860:4860::8844;
option dhcp6.domain-search "patrikx3.tk","corifeus.tk";
option dhcp6.info-refresh-time 21600;

subnet6 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::/64 {
    range6 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::1000 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::ffff;
    range6 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::/64 temporary;

    option dhcp6.name-servers 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::20,2001:4860:4860::8888,2001:4860:4860::8844;
    option dhcp6.domain-search "patrikx3.tk","corifeus.tk";   

    host linksys {
        host-identifier option dhcp6.client-id 00:02:03:09:05:05:60:38:E0:10:A7:EB;
        fixed-address6 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::1;
    } 

    host server {
        hardware ethernet ec:aa:a0:1b:4d:84;
        fixed-address6 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::20;
    }

    host workstation {
        hardware ethernet 00:25:22:e6:5c:7f;
        fixed-address6 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::2;
    }

    host laptop {
        hardware ethernet F0:42:1c:cb:42:01;
        fixed-address6 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::4;
    }

    host printer {
        hardware ethernet 00:9C:02:2A:58:4C;
        fixed-address6 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::100;
    }
}
```

Comment: `host` declarations should be outside of the `subnet6` declaration (and are treated this way, even though you put them inside). Not sure if this answers your question, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to move hosts declaration outside of subnet declaration:

```
subnet6 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::/64 {
        range6 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::1000 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::ffff;
        range6 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::/64 temporary;

        option dhcp6.name-servers 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::20,2001:4860:4860::8888,2001:4860:4860::8844;
        option dhcp6.domain-search "patrikx3.tk","corifeus.tk";   
}
host linksys {
        host-identifier option dhcp6.client-id 00:02:03:09:05:05:60:38:E0:10:A7:EB;
        fixed-address6 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::1;
} 
...
```

Comment: Did that solve your problem? From my point of view, technically it makes no difference.