# How to declare fixed addresses for each subnet in isc-dhcp-server?

Tags: ubuntu, isc-dhcpd, subnets

On Ubuntu, I've written some host declaration in each subnet with isc-dhcp-server, and each fixed address for each network interface are successfully leased. There are plugged two network cards on this DHCP server.

But how to make corrections for this warning?

> dhcpd[11328]: WARNING: Host declarations are global.  They are not limited to the scope you declared them in.

[This post on the same warning message](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370609/isp-dhcp-server-ipv6-warning-host-declarations-are-global-they-are-not-limit) answers host declarations are out of subnet definitions. I don't think that is true in my case where two cards involved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Host definitions are always global.

So I have 3 networks on my router; "LAN" 10.0.0.0/24, "guest" 10.100.100.0/24 and "IoT" 10.100.200.0/24

My `dhcpd.conf` has the following sort of config

```
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  authoritative;
  option routers      10.0.0.1;
  blah;
}

subnet 10.100.100.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  authoritative;
  option routers      10.100.100.1;
  blah;
}

subnet 10.100.200.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  authoritative;
  option routers      10.100.200.1;
  blah;
}

host machine1 {
  hardware ethernet xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx;
  fixed-address 10.0.0.13;
  option host-name "machine1";
}

host machine2 {
  hardware ethernet yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy;
  fixed-address 10.100.200.15;
  option host-name "machine2";
}
```

DHCPd correctly works out that `machine1` is on LAN and `machine2` is on the IoT subnet and sends the correct configuration (netmask, default route, DNS server etc etc) relevant to that subnet.

If you have a machine that can connect to multiple interfaces and you want them to get different addresses then you can list the host multiple times.  For example, my cellphone:

```
host s8 {
  hardware ethernet aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa;
  fixed-address 10.0.0.34;
  option host-name "s8";
}

host s8-guest {
  hardware ethernet aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa;
  fixed-address 10.100.100.9;
  option host-name "s8-guest";
}
```

Now it'll will get a different address, depending on what network it is on.

If there's no static entry for that network then it'll get a dynamic address.  If there's no free addresses on the subnet then it won't get assigned any address.

Comment: This will lease the same address if they connect from the other interface. It's not what I want.

Comment: It doesn't.  if you don't have a static entry on that network (see my update on how you can do this) then it'll try and get a dynamic one.   If there's no dynamic address available on the subnet then it won't get any assigned address.  DHCPd is pretty smart :-)

Comment: Thanks. I got the right address.